# How to make status bar icon persistent and visible even though there are already many ongoing event icon in tray?

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar, notificationmanager

I want to put a icon on status bar (done). 
It should be visible all the time like Skype does.
Other new notification or ongoing event icons should not able to hide my app icon.
I want my icon to be in front of any other ongoing event icons.
Currently I am using

```
Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR |Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT
```

to make icon as ongoing event.

Following screen shot shows Skype notification always be there at 2nd position even though new ongoing events added later.

This is not applicable to my app.

How to get that behavior??

Please check following screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0HwB.png

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot set the order explicitly because it is managed by the notification service. The behavior you mentioned is most likely because skype's notification does not have a 'when' field thus it is always before notifications having 'when' (e.g. 12:46 PM) fields.

See:

```
new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but I thought it may be helpful to someone who is looking for a similar answer:

```
.setOngoing(true)
```

as an attribute in Notification.Builder, to set whether this is an "ongoing" notification.